# Python Random function

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, random, count, range

Write a program to create an array of random numbers between 1000 to 2000
and count the number of values that are higher than 1500.

I've kind of have the understanding of setting the range, but not counting the number of returns.

What I have is this:

```
import random
for x in range(20): 
     a=random.randint(1000,2000) 
     b=(a>1500) 
     print b 
print
```

this simply returns Trues or Falses, I need to know the total number of numbers over 1500 not if they are or aren't Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think I fixed my post, sorry for it being crap

Comment: If you get in the habit of giving your variables descriptive names, it will really pay off in the long-run.  Names like `a` and `b` won't cause trouble in 5 lines of code that you just wrote, but when it's 500 lines of code and you're looking at it 6 months later you're gonna wanna kick your earlier incarnation where it really hurts.

Comment: I appreciate the insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it, assuming your original code is correct in other respects:

```
import random
count = 0
for x in range(20): 
     a=random.randint(1000,2000) 
     # b=(a>1500)// This is expected to give a boolean 
     # print b 
     if (a > 1500):
        count = count + 1

print count
```